# Get value from nested array (json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Im trying to get value from an array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "5899aaa321e01b8b050041cb",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "picture": {"small": "https://cdn.image.com/1234"},
    "age": 28,
    "location": {"city": "London"},
    "following": 1,
    "resources": {"band": "http://image/music"},
    "top_works": [
      {
        "points": 20,
        "portfolio": {
        "facebook_id": "1e691681472",
        "picture": {"small": "https://cdn.image.com/1234"}
        }
      },
      {
        "points": 10,
        "portfolio": {
        "facebook_id": "1e6916r17ry",
        "picture": {"small": "https://cdn.image.com/1234"}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/url/123',
    data: { get_param: 'value' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (index, element) {
        $('#api').append('<div>'
        + ' <div><h3>' + element.name + '</h3></div>'
        + '<div>' + element.top_works[2].portfolio.picture.small + '></div>');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I can read without problem all, neither the "top_works, because i need to specific the number [x], and I need a loop.

In some case if the top_works is empty i get an "undefined in console", i need to show a white space if the element does'nt exsist.

Someone can help me?

Comment: what is the input and what the output? and what have you tried?

Comment: Your array is not correctly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should verify if that exists, something like:

```
$.each(data, function (index, element) {
    var HTML = '<div>'
    + ' <div><h3>' + element.name + '</h3></div>';
    var exists = element.top_works[2] && element.top_works[2].portfolio && element.top_works[2].portfolio.picture && element.top_works[2].portfolio.picture.small;
    HTML+= exists ? '<div>' + element.top_works[2].portfolio.picture.small + '</div>' : '<div>#empty space</div>';
    $('#api').append(HTML + '</div>');
});
```

But if you want to search for a picture on the last index, maybe you can do this:

```
$.each(data, function (index, element) {
    var HTML = '<div>'
    + ' <div><h3>' + element.name + '</h3></div>';
    var last = element.top_works ? element.top_works.length-1 : -1;
    var exists = last >= 0;
    HTML+= exists ? '<div>' + element.top_works[last].portfolio.picture.small + '</div>' : '<div>#empty space</div>';
    $('#api').append(HTML + '</div>');
});
```

## EDIT

For a loop, you can do this:

```
$.each(data, function (index, element) {
    var HTML = '<div>'
    + ' <div><h3>' + element.name + '</h3></div>';
    if(element.top_works && element.top_works.length > 0) {
        for(var i in element.top_works) {
            HTML+= '<div>' + element.top_works[i].portfolio.picture.small + '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        HTML += '<div>#empty space</div>';
    }
    $('#api').append(HTML + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you this works! The second code, but if i wanna to get more top_works? With this i get the last element...mm..if u want to get 3?

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of `array.length` property to check if and element exists or not as shown in following example.

```js
var topWorks = { "top_works": [
      {
        "points": 20,
        "portfolio": {
          "facebook_id": "1e691681472",
          "picture": {
            "small": "https://cdn.image.com/1234",
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "points": 10,
        "portfolio": {
          "facebook_id": "1e6916r17ry",
          "picture": {
            "small": "https://cdn.image.com/1234",
          }
        }
      },
    ]
}

if(topWorks.top_works.length > 0) {
 console.log("Top works has element at index 0");
}

if(topWorks.top_works.length > 1) {
 console.log("Top works has element at index 1");
}

if(topWorks.top_works.length > 2) {
 console.log("Top works has element at index 2");
}else 
{
  console.log("Top works does not have element at index 2");
}
```